# Using replace with an Eval in the Master Page

Tags: master-page, evaluation

I am trying to replace all the spaces in my title to use as an ID, but I keep getting this error: 
error CS0103: The name 'Replace' does not exist in the current context

The code I am using is this:
id="<%# Eval(Replace("Title"," ", "")) %>

id="<%# Eval("Title") %> works like a dream, and I have tried various ways to get the spaces removed, like Trim and Replace, but each gives me the above error.

can you help me format the right eval please? I am using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise edition.

Thanks
Louise

Comment: It seems like such a silly thing - but any .replace / .trims dont have definitions?

Comment: id="<%# Eval("Title").Replace(" ", "") %>"  brings back :error CS0117: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Replace'

Answer (score 2):

My colleague gave me this ; id="<%# Eval("Title").ToString().Replace(" ", "") %>" and it worked! - Thanks for the help Christian!

Answer (score 0):

could jQuery be an option for you? I think you can do this with an string replace function.

Comment: A friend suggested: String.Replace(Eval("Title"), " ", "") but I got this: error CS1501: No overload for method 'Replace' takes '3' arguments . Jquery is an option for me :)